# htaccess remove trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, trailing-slash

I have following htaccess: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]` 
and all is working fine. But now I need to remove trailing slash from url. Which means that  `http://localhost:8888/folder_app/en/psssses/index/asd/` (notice the trailing slash) will redirect to `http://localhost:8888/folder_app/en/psssses/index/asd` without trailing slash...
Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder_app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but not as I expected. My app is in folder folder_app so url is `http://localhost:8888/folder_app` , and your code redirect to root `http://localhost:8888/`.. Do you know how to redirect to current folder? Thanks